# Natural Language Parsing using Stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

How Stanford natural Language Parser uses Penn Tree Bank for Tagging process ? I want to know how it finds the POS for the given input?

Comment: give a little bit more detail and what you have tried please.

Answer (score 3):

The Stanford part-of-speech tagger uses a probabilistic sequence model to determine the most likely sequence of part-of-speech tags underlying a sentence. Some of the features provided to this model are

- Surrounding words and n-grams
- Part-of-speech tags of surrounding words
- "Word shapes" (e.g., "Foo5" is translated to "Xxx#")
- Word suffix, prefix

See the [`ExtractorFrames` class](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/ExtractorFrames.html) for details. The model is trained on a tagged corpus (like the Penn Treebank) which has each token annotated with its correct part of speech.

At run time, features like those mentioned above are calculated for input text and are used to build per-tag probabilities, which are then fed into an implementation of the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) ([`ExactBestSequenceFinder`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/sequences/ExactBestSequenceFinder.html)), which finds the most likely arrangement of tags for the entire sequence.

For more information to get started with POS tagging:

- Watch the [Week 5 lectures of the Coursera NLP class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/natural-language-processing/home/week/5) (co-taught by the CoreNLP lead)
- Check out the code in the [`edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/package-summary.html) package
- [Part-of-speech tagging in NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)